# How to get Server Version CRM 2011 or CRM 2013 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create a JS file which can differentiate between 2011 and 2013 versions of DCRM. Is there some function I can use or some way to check JS is being executed on CRM 2011 and not on CRM 2013.

I want to create a common code for CRM 2011 and CRM 2013 solutions and few specific tasks will be handled accordingly to the server used.

I am fine if there is some client side function which gives exception in 2013, in catch block I will handle it and will differentiate. But it "should not give a server side hit" anyhow.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if a CRM2013-only JavaScript function is defined, if not the script is running under CRM 2011, otherwise it is CRM 2013.

For example using the `setFormNotification`

```js
var isCRM2013 = false;
if (Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification !== undefined)
{
    isCRM2013 = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use RetreiveVesrion message to get actual version of CRM. In case it starts from 5 - then it is CRM 2011, in case it starts from 6 then - CRM 2013. Recheck following [sample](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/06/get-version-number-of-microsoft.html)